# delete similar countries names in each row in r

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset with a sample column from it shown below.

I need to delete similar countries names in each row (MAIN REQUEST)

then I need to create a column for each country (SUPPLEMENTARY REQUEST).

```
data<-read.table(text="
LocationCountry
United States, Belgium, France, Ireland, Netherlands, Netherlands, Netherlands, Sweden
Spain, Spain, Spain, Spain
Korea, Republic of
Korea, Republic of
Austria, Austria, Austria
United States, United States, United States, United States, United States, United States
Italy, Italy
Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of, Korea, Republic of
India, Iran, Islamic Republic of
Spain, Spain, Spain, Spain
Korea, Republic of
Turkey, Turkey", header=T, sep="\n")
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The first part is very easy. Second part is confusing. You mean create a column for each country in a different DataFrame?

Comment: @Amit  Thanks. I need it in the same dataset, if possible. Otherwise, I have a serial number for each row in my large dataset so I can merge if needed.

Comment: Some of the countries have `,` in between i.e. `Korea, Republic of`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use  `strsplit` to split into a `list`, get the `unique` elements and `paste` them back

```
data$LocationCountry <- sapply(strsplit(data$LocationCountry, ",\\s*"), 
       function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

-output

```
data
#                                                LocationCountry
#1  United States, Belgium, France, Ireland, Netherlands, Sweden
#2                                                         Spain
#3                                            Korea, Republic of
#4                                            Korea, Republic of
#5                                                       Austria
#6                                                 United States
#7                                                         Italy
#8                                            Korea, Republic of
#9                              India, Iran, Islamic Republic of
#10                                                        Spain
#11                                           Korea, Republic of
#12                                                       Turkey
```

---

For the supplementary part, if we need to create binary columns for each element in the 'LocationCountry', then use the updated 'LocationCountry' column with unique names, split it, and apply the `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(data, mtabulate(strsplit(data$LocationCountry, ",\\s+")))
```

-output

```
                                             LocationCountry Austria Belgium France India Iran Ireland Islamic Republic of Italy
1  United States, Belgium, France, Ireland, Netherlands, Sweden       0       1      1     0    0       1                   0     0
2                                                         Spain       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
3                                            Korea, Republic of       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
4                                            Korea, Republic of       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
5                                                       Austria       1       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
6                                                 United States       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
7                                                         Italy       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     1
8                                            Korea, Republic of       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
9                              India, Iran, Islamic Republic of       0       0      0     1    1       0                   1     0
10                                                        Spain       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
11                                           Korea, Republic of       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
12                                                       Turkey       0       0      0     0    0       0                   0     0
   Korea Netherlands Republic of Spain Sweden Turkey United States
1      0           1           0     0      1      0             1
2      0           0           0     1      0      0             0
3      1           0           1     0      0      0             0
4      1           0           1     0      0      0             0
5      0           0           0     0      0      0             0
6      0           0           0     0      0      0             1
7      0           0           0     0      0      0             0
8      1           0           1     0      0      0             0
9      0           0           0     0      0      0             0
10     0           0           0     1      0      0             0
11     1           0           1     0      0      0             0
12     0           0           0     0      0      1             0
```

Comment: Thx for your feedback. I tried it but it gives me this `Error in strsplit(data$LocationCountry, ",\\s*") : non-character argument` . Also, would it be possible to help with the supplementary request above,if possible? Upvote

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Okay, the reason is that you have `factor` column.  Convert to `character` i.e. `sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$LocationCountry), ",\\s*"), 
       function(x) toString(unique(x)))`  From R 4.0, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default.  May be you have a R version that is old.

Comment: Yes It works now. I have `R version 3.6.2`. Would it be possible to help with the supplementary question?. Upvoted.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Can you show what the values would be in that column so that i can crosscheck

Comment: @MohamedRahouma can you please try the updated solution

Comment: That works. Greatly appreciated and accepted as a solution. and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code1
data %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(LocationCountry,sep=',') %>%
  mutate(LocationCountry=trimws(LocationCountry)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(LocationCountry)) %>%
  summarise(LocationCountry=paste0(LocationCountry,collapse = ', ')) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 1
   LocationCountry                                             
   <chr>                                                       
 1 United States, Belgium, France, Ireland, Netherlands, Sweden
 2 Spain                                                       
 3 Korea, Republic of                                          
 4 Korea, Republic of                                          
 5 Austria                                                     
 6 United States                                               
 7 Italy                                                       
 8 Korea, Republic of                                          
 9 India, Iran, Islamic Republic of                            
10 Spain                                                       
11 Korea, Republic of                                          
12 Turkey
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the point raised by @akrun makes it a complicated that some countries have a comma between them. However here is my solution. Not much different than that of @akrun.

```
RemoveRedundants <- function(Row){
  Split_Countries <- unlist(strsplit(Row, ", "))
  Unique_Countries <- paste(unique(Split_Countries, fromLast = TRUE), collapse = ", ")
  return(Unique_Countries)
}

data$UniqueCountries <- apply(data,1,RemoveRedundants)
View(data)
```

Gives the following as the output
[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for your precious input In your code `data$UniqueCountries <- apply(data,1,RemoveRedundants)`, is there any way that I use column name rather than `1`  as this column is not number 1. Also, would it be possible to help in the supplementary request above. Upvoted.

Comment: 1 is the margin. If it is 1 that means you wish to apply the function for every row ..if it is 2 then you wish to apply for every column. I am guessing what you need by the supplementary request .. For each unique country you need a column so that  each cell of each of these new columns will be filled later by some sort of logic later? right?

Comment: Thx a lot. Yes, I need eg a column named India with1 if the row has India and 0 if it doesn't have, etc. for other countries.